# How to make a one-liner for creating of 2D array of typed objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, for-loop

I am trying to figure out, is there a chance to replace code below with something more simple? In my code I am creating a 10x10 game board, where I am using `for`, [with similar approach as here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/twoarray1.shtml):

```
    let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      arr[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = {
          row: j,
          col: i,
          value: 0,
          color: 'rgba(0, 162, 255, 0.2)',
          elX: -1,
          elY: -1,
        };
      }
    };
```

Can we do it without using of `for` iteration?

Creating empty array is quite simple. We can find how to do it here:

- [w3docs](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript.html),
- [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript/),
- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/966225/12603542)

And after this we can assign values like this:

```
arr[i][j] = {...};
```

But still we need to use `for` iteration. I have a fealing that `fill` might be a key to sole this problem, used in this answer, but still I have no clue how to populate the array:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49201210/12603542

Comment: let x;
let board = (x=(i: any)=>Array(10).fill(i))(x(1));
console.log(board);

Comment: @ThomasSablik Allright, I updated the code for pure JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.from` will simplify.

```js
const val = (i, j) => ({
  row: j,
  col: i,
  value: 0,
  color: "rgba(0, 162, 255, 0.2)",
  elX: -1,
  elY: -1,
});

const vals2d = (len = 10) =>
  Array.from({ length: len }, (_, i) =>
    Array.from({ length: len }, (_, j) => val(i, j))
  );
  
console.log(vals2d())
```